# TinyMCE | Paste as plain Text + Blank Lines

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-plugins

I would like to know if there is anyway to keep **paste_as_text: true,**
But keep the **blank lines** / new lines, when paste something to TinyMCE.

I´m uploading my code below. Already searched alot on web, and didn´t found any answer.
Thanks for anyone help.

Try to pase this text:

**"this text you should**

**paste to the editor for testing"**

-> You see, the blank line between the phrases, is not pasting

```
tinymce.init({
   selector: '#mytextarea',
   height: "calc(100vh - 90px)",
   width: "100%",
   plugins: "paste",
   paste_as_text: true,
   force_br_newlines: true,
   force_p_newlines: false,
   forced_root_block: 'div',
   
   setup: function (editor) {
      editor.on('init', function (e) {
      editor.setContent('');
      editor.getBody().style.fontSize = '13px';
      editor.getBody().style.fontFamily = 'Arial';
      });
```

Comment: which version if tinymce do you use? I tried your config here https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/u4daab/2 and pasted something from google docs and other website into the editor, but for me it kept all the line breaks

Comment: Sorry for the missunderstood, what i´m loosing is the *blank lines* / new lines, for example, if you paste the text below to the editor:

"this text you should

paste to the editor for testing"

You see, the blank line between the phrases, is not pasting.

I update the ask description.

Comment: oh, now I see the problem.
When forcing root blocks with `forced_root_block: 'div'` option, the editor converts all double new lines to single new line https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/blob/develop/modules/tinymce/src/plugins/paste/main/ts/core/Newlines.ts#L51

Try setting `forced_root_block: false,`, would that work for you?

Comment: Wow, nice! It would helps the problem, but I can not remove ```forced_root_block: 'div'```, because i have another function that is listening the keypress, and don´t works fine with another block type.

**https://github.com/RadioLaudos/tinymce_text/blob/main/textarea**

Comment: Since you seem to have new lines `\n` instead of line breaks `\r`, I see no way to actually determine which one of them actually are supposed to be line breaks in a sentence, that belongs together, and which not. You might try to edit the tinymce plugin file and replace double new line `\n\n` with a single new line. But i'm afraid this could mess up other parts of the pasted content. If you paste from HTML code, i would try using custom `paste_preprocess` function and replace new lines inside a single tag with line breaks.

Comment: @Marat Understood, both are good ideas, how can i edit the tinymce plugin file? Also is any guide for paste_preprocess? I would like to contact you if you interested on the job, my email radiolaudos@radiolaudos.com thanks a lot

Comment: there is a basic example for paste_preprocess in the docs: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/paste/#exampleusingpaste_preprocess

Comment: I think you should go for regex replace, try this one https://regex101.com/r/fiN36Z/1/
(sorry, i have no time for any new jobs right now)

Comment: =) Thanks alot my friend. I will try it. It seems to be a little hard for coding. i´m still on the process of studying.